# Best Location to write the Session code to check if Session Exists

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

## Using : PHP MVC CI

I created a Controller class with the name of `My_Controller` in `Core Folder`. In this `class`, It is being checked if the `session` exists or not. This `controller` is being extended in all controller classes. Here is the code

```
<?php
    class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();      
            $this->load->library('session')
            if(empty($this->session->userdata('userName')) {
                header('Location: '."Login Url");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Question: Is there any better location to write the `Session` code in MVC Architecture ??

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the hook in CI and check the session over there.
Hook will call in every request so you can write permission role over there.

Here is more detail how you can write the hook.

> http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: Yes but the he need where he can write the session code to manage the login access so by using hook he did not require to write the condition in each controller file.

Comment: He also ask `Question: Is there any better location to write the Session code in MVC Architecture ??` that's why i give ans hook is the way from where you can manage request.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `session_start();`

**In Controller**

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();      

    }

    public function index($value)
    {
        $session = $this->model_name->check_session();
        if($session==true){
            #valid code         
        }
        else{
            redirect('controller/method');
        }
    }
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function log_in()
{
    $log = $this->session->all_userdata();

    if (isset($log['userName'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

create a file name auth_hook.php in hook folder and write this code

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth_hook extends CI_Controller {

    private $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
    }

    public function is_authorized() {
        $uri = $this->CI->uri->segment(1);
        if (strcmp($uri, 'user') && $uri != '') {

            if ($this->CI->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
                return true;
            } else {
                redirect(site_url('user'));
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: IF you will write this code in the hook file you do not need to write any code in the controller. Each time when your controller will run it will check for the session first.